# How can I pass a specific value related to a specific element into a list when I click an icon into my Angular application?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular project and I am now facing a problem for which I don't know what could be a good solution.

Basically I have this section into my application containing a list of persons:

[image]

As you can see each person have a name, at the moment something like **PERSONA 1**, **PERSONA 2**, etc.
Next to each person there is a funnel icon that once clicked it will perform a method that filter for the specific person.

This is the view code of my **people-list** component (the one showing the People list on the left of the previous screenshot):

```
<p-selectButton [options]="workShiftTypes" [(ngModel)]="selectedShift" optionLabel="name"></p-selectButton>
<p>Selected Work Shift: {{selectedShift ? selectedShift.value : 'none'}}</p>

<div class="custom_sift" *ngIf="selectedShift.value == 'custom'">
  <app-custom-event-date-selector
                (notifyStartEndTime)="onChangeCustomShiftDate($event)">
  </app-custom-event-date-selector>
</div>

<div #draggable_people>

  <p-orderList [value]="people" [listStyle]="{'height':'400px'}" header="People"
    filter="filter" filterBy="name" filterPlaceholder="Filter by name" dragdrop="true">
    <ng-template let-person pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix fc-event" style="background-color: transparent; color:black !important;border: 0px !important;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm">
                <img src="assets/img/people/person-icon.png" style="display:inline-block;float: left; margin:2px 20px 2px 2px" width="48">
                <div style="font-size:14px;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{person.name}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="people-operations-icons">
                  <button class="btn" (click)="onClickFilter($event)">
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-funnel-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-orderList>
</div>
```

As you can see in this HTML code I have this line:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="onClickFilter($event)">
```

that call the **onClickFilter()** method on the component typescript code passing the click event. It works fine but I noticed that doing in this way the passed event doesn't contain the information related the person name related ot the clicked funnel element.

A first idea could be pass the **person.name** value contained into:

```
<div style="font-size:14px;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{person.name}}</div>
```

But I am absolutly not sure of this.

What is a good way to implement this behavior? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you just pass the `person` object as parameter in your `onClickFilter`?

```
<button class="btn" (click)="onClickFilter(person, $event)">
```